# I am trying create standard logic app with workflows in it using arm template

Tags: workflow, azure-logic-apps, standards

Ii am trying to create standard logic app using arm template with workflows in it, but it only creates standard logic app without workflow.At the same time it creates consumption logic app also.

I tried adding microsoft.logic/workflows under resources and added action and trigger inside. But this is not helping

Comment: So give us something to work with. There’s plenty of documentation action on how to deploy a standard logicapp

Comment: You try to create template  simple standard logic app with workflows in it and deploy using arm template, see that once logic app. Is created workflow should also be added

Answer (score 0):

microsoft.logic/workflows is used for Consumption Logic Apps - not for Standard Logic Apps, which are essentially well camouflaged Function Apps.

The workflows in Standard Logic Apps are nothing more than workflow.json files in respective folders.

If you already managed to create Standard Logic Apps using ARM templates, you can deploy workflows, connections, settings, etc. (see the folder structure [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/edit-app-settings-host-settings?tabs=azure-portal#visual-studio-code-project-structure)) into the Standard Logic Apps e.g. using the [az logicapp deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/logicapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az-logicapp-deployment-source-config-zip) command or [Azure Functions Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-function-app-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task in Azure DevOps pipelines.